# How to make slider automatically in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, slider, swipe

I want to question for my problem about a Slider/Swipe, i want the slider can move automatically.

so, I have a page php with Slider/Swipe, but its not move automatically, how to make the slider automatic move.

please help for my problem, I really hope for your help, thank you all

this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tmp_home_swipe/css/swiper.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" /> -->

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 70%;
    }
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container" id="slideshow">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>


  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="tmp_home_swipe/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks for attention.

Comment: If you looked at the swiper web site you would find that they have demos. The one you are looking for is: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/280-autoplay.html. The documentation can be found on http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/ and scroll down to Autoplay or the source code is also available at: https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/280-autoplay.html

Comment: oh yaa works like a charm. thanks @jeff, my problem solved now.

Comment: There is no PHP in this question. Since you are using Boostrap you could use carousel that comes built into Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
});
```

https://themesbrand.com/velzon/docs/php/swiper-slider.html